# php POST certain elements with class

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I will have html like this:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <ul class="select_list">
            <li id="s1" class="chosen">Apple</li>
            <li id="s2" style="display: none;">Peach</li>
            <li id="s3" style="display: none;">Plum</li>
            <li id="s4" class="chosen">Banana</li>
            <li id="s5" style="display: none;">Grapes</li>
            <li id="s6" class="chosen">Pear</li>
            <li id="s7" style="display: none;">Kiwi</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

how can I use $_POST to get the ids of the elements with class="chosen"

Comment: To get the data from `$_POST` you will have to use form elememnts with name, By javascript you can get the data like this.

Comment: @SumanBogati like hidden input elements?

Comment: By form hidden input elements you can do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "direct" way to do this. Forms POST data from `input`, `textarea`, and `button` elements, possibly a few more I'm forgetting. You will have to use JavaScript to "transcribe" the `li` elements to one of these, possibly an `<input type="hidden">`. For instance:

```
var form = $formselector
form.onsubmit = function() {
    var chosen = form.getElementsByClassName("chosen");
    for (var i=0; i<chosen.length; i++) {
        form.innerHTML += '<input type="hidden" name="chosen[]" value="'+chosen[i].id+'">';
    }
}
```

This should loop through your form, finding all elements with class chosen and adding a hidden input with the ID of that element. Note that you might need to change the `name` of the hidden input element to match your server-side code. Also make sure you update `$formselector` to actually match your form.

Comment: i got Uncaught ReferenceError: form is not defined  see my answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a hidden input and assign value to it by javascript or jquery.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">

<input type="hidden" name="my_data" value="" />

<div class="form-group">
    <ul class="select_list">
        <li id="s1" class="chosen">Apple</li>
        <li id="s2" style="display: none;">Peach</li>
        <li id="s3" style="display: none;">Plum</li>
        <li id="s4" class="chosen">Banana</li>
        <li id="s5" style="display: none;">Grapes</li>
        <li id="s6" class="chosen">Pear</li>
        <li id="s7" style="display: none;">Kiwi</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>

<script>
$('.select_list').change(function(){
    $('.my_data').val($(this).val());
});
</script>
```

Try this...

Comment: tried to figure out how this works but it doesnt example please?

Comment: Does my given example won't work??? You need to add jquery file in head section to enable jquery.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
var value = [];
$('.chosen').each(function(){
    value.push(this.id.substring(1));
});
$('.form-horizontal').submit(function(){
    $('.form-horizontal').append('<input type="hidden" value="' + value +'"/>');
}
```